# Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document in magento2.3.0

Tags: admin, magento2.3.0

In magento 2.3.0 for new module is throws an exception like below image url
http://prntscr.com/n7rpgb

my acl.xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">
                <resource id="Ram_Seller::seller" title="Seller" sortOrder="100"/>
 <!--AddMenuAcl-->
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Ram_Seller::seller" title="Seller" sortOrder="100"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

It says the **resource** **title** is missing in your **`acl.xml`** file. check sample below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Ram_Seller::seller" title="Seller"
                          translate="title" sortOrder="900"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

EDIT: you should use **`Magento_Backend::admin`** instead of **`Magento_Adminhtml::admin`** in your resource id after resources.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your acl.xml with the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Ram_Seller::seller" title="Seller" sortOrder="100"/>
             <!--AddMenuAcl-->
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

**ISSUE :**

The issue with resource id, that's invalid,

It should be **Magento_Backend** instead of **Magento_AdminHtml**